# Jenkins Publish to Separate Repo than Source Managed

Tags: github, jenkins

I'm trying to write a job in Jenkins that pulls my latest code from a Github repo, zips it all up, and then pushes it to another builds Github repo. The Publisher event in post-build seems to only push back to the repo you specify in source code management. Is there a way I can push to a different/separate repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the zip and than use a bash command with git push ...
Another option is to keep the zip in artifacts repository - Nexus or artifactory ...